# Python Qualified Import all in Package

Tags: python, package, web-frameworks

Alright, so I have a file with controllers for various pages of a site. Let's say the following structure.

```
/controllers
    /login_controller.py
    /main_controller.py
    /and_so_forth
```

I know that you can dynamically load all defined symbols in the folder controllers by using this snipped in the `__init__.py`:

```
__all__ = []

import pkgutil
import inspect

for loader, name, is_pkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(__path__):
    module = loader.find_module(name).load_module(name)

    for name, value in inspect.getmembers(module):
        if name.startswith('__'):
            continue

        globals()[name] = value
        __all__.append(name)
```

The thing is, I do like qualified imports. So say each controller file has one controller function defined. Is there any way to achieve the behaviour with `__init__.py` magic so that when I do:

```
import controllers
```

I can call the functions as

```
controllers.controller_function_name()
```

instead of:

```
controllers.module_name.controller_function_name()
```

? Removing the middle-man. Essentially, have it behave as if it was just a module.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You'll need to import within `__init__.py` whatever you want to be available.  If you want to change the names (e.g., so that `controller()` in `main.py` becomes `main_controller`), you'll have to handle that mapping yourself.

Comment: @BrenBarn Sorry, edited the question so that it is clearer. I don't want to change the name; I just want to dynamically import all the modules of a package without losing name qualification.

Comment: Your edit still leaves something unclear though.  Now when you do `controllers.controller()`, which controller are you expecting that to call?  The one in `login_controler` or the one in `main_controller`?

Comment: @BrenBarn No! The `controller()` is just an example name. Assume there will be no conflicts.

Comment: If I understand you right, your code should already be doing that.  When you do `globals()[name] = value` you are adding the function to the namespace of `__init__`, so it should be available under the top-level package.

Comment: @BrenBarn right, but the problem is that it is the equivalent of `from module import *`; it's not qualified. I want the functions to be qualified with the name of the folder.

Comment: If you use your code and then do `import controllers`, you should be able to then do `controllers.controller_function_name` just as you say you want.  The `__all__` business is not needed for this.

Comment: @BrenBarn oh that's interesting. So should I remove the `globals()[name]` business so that it doesn't pollute the local namespace?

Comment: No, you *need* the `globals` part.  What you don't need is the `__all__` part.  The global namespace of `__init__.py` defined what will be available under the package.  That is, if you create a name `x` in `controllers/__init__.py`, then you will be able to do `controllers.x`.

Comment: @BrenBarn Oh OK. I understand now. I think I was not very clear on how defining things in `__init__.py` worked. I didn't know that defining something in the `__init__.py` actually allowed it to be qualified with the package name of the package that contained the `__init__.py`. Thanks! Perhaps put this as an answer for future inquirers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, your code already lets you do what you want to do.

When you do `globals()[name] = value`, you create a global variable in `__init__.py`.  Global variables in `__init__.py` are what determines what is available under the package namespace.  So if in your code you wind up creating a variable `some_controller` in `__init__.py`, then you will be able to do `controllers.some_controller`.

`__all__` only affects what is imported when you use `from module import *`.  By modifying `__all__`, you are affecting what will happen if you do `from controllers import *`, but you're not affecting what will be available under `controllers` if you just do `import controllers`.

Comment: but what I _can_ remove is the `__all__.append(name)` part, without changing what the result is, correct?

Comment: @Aristides: Basically yes, `__all__` only affects the `from foo import *` form.  See my edited answer.